# Deployment versioning between sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, change-set, version-control

We are currently having problems attempting version control between several sandboxes. We would like to be able to confirm when Sandbox_A is in synch with Sandbox_B. We are thinking we can just name a Change Set to the version of the deployment. (ie 'v_1.1') - and then compare the Change Set histories of the two environments. Is that the expected way of monitoring two sandboxes, or is there a better 'Best Practice' method ?

Comment: Why not to use sfdx/ant to retrieve metadata and do diff on folder (version control system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for DevOps process to keep two or more sandboxes in sync.
Use sfdx to retrieve complete metadata.
Have a version control tool like BitBucket/Source tree to compare and merge the differences.
With Integration tool like Jenkins, run build which will take care of test class coverage also.
Deploy the changes via ANT.

There are many other tools like GitHub etc, which you can use in long term to keep a sync in all of your sandboxes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a vendor product like [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) which can run Continuous Integration between a source sandbox and a target sandbox (in addition to also working with source control if you desire)

Details on the [Gearset CI feature are here](https://gearset.com/product/continuous-integration). You can choose which metadata types you want to keep in sync as the source sandbox changes.

*N.B. I am not an employee of Gearset but do use it in our org*

Comment: Thank you - we do intend to look into Gearset. I was just hoping to get some rudimentary temporary solution going in the meantime. Thanks again.